# Is it possible to manually put the page number when \thispagestyle{empty} is active?

Tags: header-footer, page-numbering

I would like to put the command `\thispagestyle{empty}` after the beginning of a certain chapter and to put manually the page number at the same position, i.e., without invoking `\thispagestyle{plain}` or similar commands. Note that I don't know what is the number of that page, so the page number should be determined automatically.
Is it possible?

For example in the following document I would like to manually put the page number 2 (of course 2 should be determined automatically) at the bottom of page 2.

```
\documentclass{report}

\begin{document}
\chapter{1}
\chapter{2}
\thispagestyle{empty}

\end{document}
```

Comment: If you want to put `\thispagestyle`, it's not more difficult to type `\thispagestyle{plain}`, is it?

Comment: @egreg this question is related to my previous question http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/208492/makeindex-error-when-using-tableofcontents-or-chapter-with-arabi-package In fact I realized that by putting \thispagestyle{empty} after the beginning of every chapter and after \tableofcontents makeindex seems to work. So if I could put the page numbers manually my problem is solved.

Comment: The macro `\thepage` contains the current number, whether the pagination is visible or not. To place it you can use – kind of overkill – `tike.sty` and absolute positioning with `current page` nodes. Another option is to define a new page style containing only the page number.

Comment: @Tobi I would be grateful if you could elaborate more. I am a beginner in LaTeX.

Comment: Yes, it can be done using \AddThisPagehook from the everypage package and \raisebox, but you need to calculate precisely where to place the page number relative to the upper left corner.

Comment: This is _exactly_ what `\thispagestyle` is defined to do, why would you not want to use it? If you don't want to use it you can copy its definition but that's just strange.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle as I wrote in my previous comment above, the reason for not wanting to use thispagestyle is a conflict of makeindex and non-latin characters as pointed out by egreg in my previous question http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/208492/makeindex-error-when-using-tableofcontents-or-chapter-with-arabi-package and I realized by using \thispagestyle{empty} one can overcome by this conflict. So I should put the page numbers manually and this is the motivation of my question.

Comment: @Name sorry that makes no sense:-) makeindex will use the same information whatever the pagestyle, which just affects whether the header is printed on the page it has no affect on the page information written to the index. The way to get a page number at the bottom and no page header is to use `\thispagestyle{plain}` any other method of getting that is either equivalent or excessively over complicated for no reason.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Solution 0: Build in

As David said, `\thispagestyle{plain}` is the right command for this purpose (as long as you don’t say why it is impossible to use it in your case). Here’s the *magic* code ;-)

```
\documentclass{report}

\begin{document}
\chapter{1}
\chapter{2}
\thispagestyle{plain}    
\end{document}
```

The `plain` style is the default for chapter opening pages anyway …

---

But to take a sledgehammer to crack a nut – or to *shoot sparrows with cannons*, as we say in Germany – here are two other ways:

### Solution 1.1: Use `tikz` …

… to place a node on an absolute position on the page. The page is access by a named node `current page.xx`, where `xx` can be `north`, `north east` etc. for instance. Then a normal coordinate is added to shift the node to the correct position. The node is pinned to the position with its lower left (`sour east`) corner and has no margin between the (invisible) border and the content. As said in my comment the current page number is stored in `\thepage`. For more information please read the very good TikZ manual. To get the correct position the code must be compiled (at least) twice.

Here’s the code:

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{tikz}
    \usetikzlibrary{calc}

\newcommand{\onlypnum}{%
    \thispagestyle{empty}%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
        \node at ($(current page.south east)+(-20mm,10mm)$)
        [
            anchor=south east,
            inner sep=0pt,
        ]
        {%
            \thepage
        };
    \end{tikzpicture}%
    \ignorespaces
}

\begin{document}
\chapter{1}
\chapter{2}
\onlypnum
\end{document}
```

In this version the number is placed 20mm from the right and 10mm from the bottom margin. Pleas figure out the correct values yourself (you may use `\onlypnum` on a page with a regular number an try to overlay both).

### Solution 1.2: Use `tikz` …

… and the `tikzpagenodes` package. The latter package provides more nodes and makes the manual calculation/determination of the footer position obsolete. Here’s the code:

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{tikz}
    \usetikzlibrary{calc}

\usepackage{tikzpagenodes}

\newcommand{\onlypnum}{%
    \thispagestyle{empty}%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
        \node at (current page footer area.south) [
            anchor=base,
        ] {
            \thepage
        };
    \end{tikzpicture}%
    \ignorespaces
}

\begin{document}
\chapter{1}
\chapter{2}
\onlypnum
\end{document}
```

### Solution 2: New page style

To generate a new style I use `scrlayer-scrpage`, which is part of the KOMA-Script bundle. Another common package for this fast is `fancyhdr`. I define a new style `onlypnum` (actually it’s a pair of styles) that only generates the page number in the center of the foot (= `\cfoot`). The style can be used as usual with `\(this)pagestyle`. Here’s the code:

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}

\newpairofpagestyles{onlypnum}{
    \cfoot{\upshape\thepage}
}

\begin{document}
\chapter{1}
\chapter{2}
\thispagestyle{onlypnum} 
\end{document}
```

You may change `\cfoot` to suit you needs. See the KOMA-Script manual (English: `scrguien.pdf`, German: `scrguide`) for which positions are possible and further information.

Comment: why not just  `\thispagestyle{plain}` which is predefined to do this?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: Because the OP explicitly did’t want do use it ;-)

Comment: Never believe the OP:-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: Incorporated the plain way :-)

Comment: BTW, tkzpagenodes predefines node 'current page footer area".

Comment: @tobi many thanks I confirm that your solution 1 works. I was not able to test the second solution yet.

Comment: @JohnKormylo: Thanks for the hint, I didn’t know the package, which’s name starts with `tikz` and not `tkz` actually …

Answer (score 2):

Sorry -- I've just seen you want to do it for *just one chapter*. this answer reflects my inability to understand why anyone would want to do that.

---

Use `memoir` :)

In `memoir`, the first page of each chapter uses pagestyle `chapter`, which is an alias for `empty`.

You can change its behaviour globally with (in you case):

```
\aliaspagestyle{chapter}{plain}
```