# How to add space in math mode after a line break

Tags: math-mode, spacing

I want to be able to add some space at the beginning of a new line - in math mode.

What I have now is this:
[image]

What I'm aiming for is this:
[image]

I tried \hspace but it seems to be ignored when there's no to elements to space between... in other words, this will work:

```
$x\hspace{1cm} y$
```

but this will not:

```
$x\\ \hspace{1cm} y$
```

It won't let me add space between y and a new line...

Comment: As always please provide a minimal example. Having some code to start from makes everything a lot easier for the rest of ud. One question, are are you not using displayed math? Plus a comment, it is fairly easy to do with the `aligned` env from `amsmath`

Comment: You don't want to be adding space via specifying lengths just use an alignment such as `alignat` and specify the rows should align on the `=`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please always post complete documents, but you can align the lines as follows:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
G=\{&f_1=a,b,\rightarrow c,\\
&f_2=a\rightarrow b,\\
&f_3=b\rightarrow e,\\
&f_4=c\rightarrow d,e\\
&f_5=e\rightarrow d\}
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: With all due respect David, I think OP is trying to *align* the equations in the inline math. Note the text before and after equation in the original question. That's why I used `aligned` as was noted by daleif as well.

Comment: @Pouya, actually I agree with David, it ought to be displayed math. The two pictures look a lot like user that is not aware of envs for display math.

Comment: @Pouya perhaps but then the answer should be to not do that. Why have a new paragraph with a display in inline math instead of a math display? Especially as it makes  `the rest...` start a paragraph when it is really the continuation of the sentence. math displays are designed not to interrupt a paragraph.

Comment: I agree with you both as well! I myself prefer to use proper environment for displaying math. My comment was just a note on what OP is asking.

Comment: @Pouya http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/209160/is-it-possible-to-manually-put-the-page-number-when-thispagestyleempty-is-act#comment488740_209215  :-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, you should print that comment on a t-shirt `:D`. I decided to remove my answer so I would not promote a bad practice.

Comment: This is a very long document, and I didn't know if it's OK to post the whole document...

Comment: @so.very.tired no you should not post a long document but your questions should always contain a _complete_ document, like the one in this answer, that is small enough for people to test their answers without having to type it all in (as I had to here)